# In Jmeter, What would be syntax of parameters in Body Data section of HTTP Request Sampler, for Rest APIs and input should be generated dynamically

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to generate my input through JavaScript using BSF PreProcessor. Currently I've only BSF PrepProcessor and a HTTP Request. My Request body goes like this.,

```
{
    "entity": {
        "id": "${EnitityName}",
        ----
     }
}
```

The randomly generated string should be the value for ID, i've parameterized how we normaly do it. This is not working. Can somebody tell me where i'm going wrong or any alternative approach.

Comment: FYI, JMeter is not inserting the result of my script into the variable ${EntityName}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `${EnitityName}` variable is properly set in your BSF PreProcessor script, it should be substituted by the generated value **given BSF PreProcessor success**.

I would suggest checking *jmeter.log* file for any errors - it should give you an idea regarding what went wrong. You can also share your BSF PreProcessor code so others and myself could take a look and suggest the fixes.

Actually according to [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) it is recommended to use [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) so you should switch to [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](http://groovy-lang.org/), the example code which generates a random alphanumeric string of 10 characters and putting the value into the `${EntityName}` JMeter Variable will look like:

```
vars.put("EnitityName",org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10))
```

References:

- [RandomStringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html)
- [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)
- [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri.. The code u gave worked. Here is my java script which actually did not work                                                                     function generateEntityName()
{
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}
vars.put("EnitityName", generateEntityName());

Comment: I've also tried a code given by you for a similar question asked before.                                                                                     int min = Integer.parseInt(bsh.args[0]); // get first parameter
int max = Integer.parseInt(bsh.args[1]); // get second parameter
int random =  min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)); // calculate random number within parameters range
vars.put("RANDOM_NUMBER", String.valueOf(random));

Answer (score 1):

try using [__RandomString](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function: (no need of `JavaScript & BSF PreProcessor` if you want a random string)

```
{
    "entity": {
        "id": "${__RandomString(8,abcdefghiz,)}",
        ----
     }
}
```

From Docs:

Examples:

> **${__RandomString(5)}** will return a random string of 5 characters which
> can be readable or not
>
> **${__RandomString(10,abcdefg)}** will return a
> random string of 10 characters picked from abcdefg set, like
> cdbgdbeebd or adbfeggfad, …
>
> **${__RandomString(6,a12zeczclk, MYVAR)}**
> will return a random string of 6 characters picked from a12zeczclk set
> and store the result in MYVAR, MYVAR will contain string like 2z22ak
> or z11kce, …