# Syntax to use parameters in Body section of HTTP Request Sampler in JMeter, using Rest API POST request with body and input from CSV file

Tags: rest, jmeter, http-post, jmeter-5.0

I'm using JMeter to test a microservice and I need to use a parameter dynamically with a different value in each request. Also, the parameter is a part of a query that contains other constant values as well.

I defined user variables in the JMeter *user.properties* file (in JMeter *bin* folder):

**JMeter -- bin/user.properties**

```
# Parameters to use in JMeter
ES_HOST=127.0.0.1
ES_PORT=9200
ES_INDEX=segments
ES_TYPE=_doc
THREAD=5
CSVDATA_ROOT=C:/devtools/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/csv_data
```

Of course, I have *User-Defined Variables*:
[image: User Defined Variables]

And how my *Test Plan* is defined in JMeter
[image: Thread Group Users]

[image: CSV Data Set Config]

[image: HTTP Request]

As you can see in the following screenshot of *View Result Tree* the parameter **agentName** I defined and shown in the *HTTP Request* (above) is working.

I want to define it in the body of the HTTP Request, to replace the hardcoded "John Doe" with a parameters that have a different value in each request.

```
"query":"SearchStartTime=2020-01-01 00:00:00.000TO2020-01-31 23:59:59.999&AgentName=John Doe"}
```

How can I do that? 
I need a way to add a parameter to an existing string

I've already tried [Using Apache JMeter to Test Elasticsearch (or any REST API)](https://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2014/09/02/3915) and [In Jmeter, What would be syntax of parameters in Body Data section of HTTP Request Sampler, for Rest APIs and input should be generated dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549147/in-jmeter-what-would-be-syntax-of-parameters-in-body-data-section-of-http-reque) also doesn't solve my problem.

[image: View Result Tree]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use same syntax as HTTP request - `${agentname}` for getting variable value:

```
"query":"SearchStartTime=2020-01-01 00:00:00.000TO2020-01-31 23:59:59.999&AgentName=${agentname}"
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Only I need the same variable name, so all lower case:  ${agentname}